# I created a recycler view nd its not working please suggest some solution

Tags: java, android

I got this error

```
13655-13655/com.example.aviralgarg0996.imsecsupport E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.example.aviralgarg0996.imsecsupport, PID: 13655
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.aviralgarg0996.imsecsupport/com.example.aviralgarg0996.imsecsupport.CheckForWork}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.RecycleListView
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.RecycleListView
    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.RecycleListView
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.app.RecycleListView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.aviralgarg0996.imsecsupport-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.aviralgarg0996.imsecsupport-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:609)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
       at com.example.aviralgarg0996.imsecsupport.CheckForWork.onCreate(CheckForWork.java:21)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.RecycleListView Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: **Didn't find class "android.support.v7.app.RecycleListView**

Your layout file is faulty and you should replace the faulty reference to

```
android.support.v7.app.RecycleListView
```

with

```
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

Comment: Now i am getting another error :Found two getters or fields with conflicting case sensitivity for property: work_desc

Comment: You must create new question -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask - do **NOT** edit this one. It shall stay unaltered now..